# Power method to find eigenvectors of largest eigenvalues

Tags: python, eigenvalue, eigenvector

How can I implement a power method in python that can find eigenvectors corresponding to the two eigenvalues of the largest magnitude by assuring that second vector remains orthogonal to the first one? For simple case, the given matrix will be small and symmetric.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks